# SSRS parameter validation

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am using SSRS reports in MS CRM 4.0

I have two datetime parameters in my report. They are fine until someone type in an invalid format, e.g. `9/30/2008` or `40/09/2008` or random text. It logs an Error in the event log but my manager doesn’t want to see it.

Now, just wondering how to do a client side validation and stop the report gets executed if the validation failed. Or do you know how to just stop user typing into the input boxes so they can only pickup a date from the calendar control?

Any advice will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

One way to trick this into happening is using cascading parameters that depend on the date fields. If these fail to populate then the report itself will not populate.